# Creating a summation equation

Tags: summation, solution-verification

I was asked to solve a problem involving finding the number of days it will take to journey 2955 miles when: On the first day 1.5 miles are traveled and every day following he increases his journey by $\frac16$ of a mile.

I have not yet figured this out, and am looking for some help. But, I think I can set it up like this: $$\sum_{n=0}^x1.5+\frac16n$$.
This seems like it can work, but I am afraid I am missing something here.

In addition - I can solve this using a CAS calculator, but how can I do it without?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if $n$ is the number of days, you can write it as

$\sum \limits_{i=1}^n 1.5 + \frac16(i-1) = 2955$

or, $\ 1.5 n - \frac{n}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\sum \limits_{i=1}^n  i = 2955$

and $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n  i = \frac{n (n+1)}{2}$

Comment: Is your first formula any different than what I had?

Comment: Also, is it possible to explain how you got from your step one to step two?

Comment: In your formula, you start from $i = 0$. So when you find $n$, you will have to add $1$ to it as you are considering first day as $0$. Otherwise it is same.

Comment: When I solved $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2955$ and $\sum_{n=0}^x1.5+\frac16n=2955$ I got different answers...

Comment: From step 1 to step 2 is nothing but taking the constant terms (not a function of $i$) out, like $1.5$ getting added $n$ times will give you $1.5n$.

Comment: No, $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \ne 2955$. That is what $\sum_{i=1}^n i $ comes to. You need to put that in the equation before in place of  $\sum_{i=1}^n i $.

Comment: Yup. Got that. Thanks for clarifying!